# How to DRY up two functions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to *DRY up* these two Ruby functions by moving the three lines that both functions share to another function?

```
def format_currency(number)
  number_to_currency(number, 
    :unit       => current_user.currency_unit, 
    :delimiter  => current_user.currency_delimiter, 
    :separator  => current_user.currency_separator, 
    :format     => current_user.currency_format
  )
end

def format_currency_for_pdf(number, invoice)    
  number_to_currency(number / invoice.exchange_rate, 
    :unit       => CURRENCIES[invoice.currency]
    :delimiter  => current_user.currency_delimiter, 
    :separator  => current_user.currency_separator, 
    :format     => current_user.currency_format
  )
end
```

Thanks for any help?

Comment: you can merge hash into another if that worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taro suggests, it will be:

```
def format_currency(number)
  number_to_currency(number,
    currency_hash(current_user.currency_unit)
  )
end

def format_currency_for_pdf(number, invoice)
  number_to_currency(number / invoice.exchange_rate,
    currency_hash(CURRENCIES[invoice.currency])
  )
end

def currency_hash unit
  {
    :unit       => unit,
    :delimiter  => current_user.currency_delimiter,
    :separator  => current_user.currency_separator,
    :format     => current_user.currency_format
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_currency(number)
  number_to_currency(number, 
    currency_hash(current_user.currency_unit) 
  )
end

def format_currency_for_pdf(number, invoice)    
  number_to_currency(number / invoice.exchange_rate, 
    currency_hash(CURRENCIES[invoice.currency])
  )
end

def currency_hash(unit)
  {
    :unit       => unit,
    :delimiter  => current_user.currency_delimiter, 
    :separator  => current_user.currency_separator, 
    :format     => current_user.currency_format
  }
end
```

Comment: ahaha, the same solution, even method name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was thinking of a different solution by passing in format, but ended up with a different solution and forgot to remove the format

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I threw a coin and then marked zishe's answer as the correct one.